# HP 2530: multiple management IP Addresses possible?

Tags: networking, hp, switch, network-management

I have two HP 2530 switches in our hosting center. Because of some VPN problems between our office and the HC, i need to change their management IP Addresses to a different IP network.

Currently they have a 192/24 address configured in a tagged VLAN, the new network will be in the 10/16 range.

- Can I assign an Address in the new network to the same tagged VLAN that already has a management IP?
- If not, can I create a temporary VLAN and assign a second Mgmt IP to that, concurrent with the first?
- The switches have Spanning Tree (specifically MSTP) configured, how will it likely react to having multiple IP adresses - if at all?

This is in productive use, so the switches must continue to pass traffic as normal, and they also need to be reachable during the whole operation. Anything I need to look out for to ensure that?

Comment: 1. The documentation for that model suggests that you can assign multiple ip addresses to a VLAN. 2. STP operates at Layer 2, it doesn't know ip addresses so I'd be hard pressed to see how your VLAN ip address assignment would have any effect on STP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can assign multiple addresses to a management or VLAN interface. This is a handy feature for migration, or situations where you cannot modify client configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I assign an Address in the new network to the same tagged VLAN that already has a management IP?

Yes. You can assign multiple IP addresses from different subnets to any VLAN. Adding or removing addresses does *not* interrupt connections using other addresses.

> can I create a temporary VLAN and assign a second Mgmt IP to that, concurrent with the first?

That'll work as well - make sure that you haven't restricted management to a single VLAN though. If you do have you'd need to lift that restriction temporarily (`no management-vlan [x]`).

Always make sure that you can log in using the new management address before removing the old one. ;-)

> The switches have Spanning Tree (specifically MSTP) configured, how will it likely react to having multiple IP adresses - if at all?

Classic STP, RSTP and single-instance MSTP operate on the link level only. IP addresses are of no concern. MSTP can be made VLAN-aware using multiple instances - yet again, IP addresses don't matter here either.